# If there's a balanced game of 18 village members and 6 wolves, does that mean that on average, each wolf is as powerful as 3 village members?

Tags: werewolv.es

So for example, on average, a strategy that kills one wolf at the cost of 2 village members would be a good strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take the assumption in your question title to be correct, then yes, your suggested strategy would, by definition be +EV for the village to take.

It is always the responsibility of the wolves in the game to mislead the village into making incorrect lynches however, and I don't think that in a game with 18 standard villagers there would be any reliable way to create such a lynching strategy as your question proposes.

Comment: I probably should've said "village members".